# Blazor (Server Side) Error Uncaught ReferenceError: LoginContributor is not defined

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Running into a strange issue.  This is a Blazor App (Server Side) using .NET Core 3.1

I created a new Blazor App to reproduce this.  I modified the Counter example and modified it to the following:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<EditForm Model="@loginData" OnValidSubmit="LoginContributor">
    <div class="login-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="UserNameEdit" class="col-form-label">Username:</label>
                <InputText id="UserNameEdit" @bind-Value="loginData.Username"></InputText>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="PasswordEdit" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                <InputText id="PasswordEdit" @bind-Value="loginData.Password" type="password"></InputText>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="LoginContributor">Log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <InputCheckbox id="SaveLoginEdit" @bind-Value="loginData.SaveLoginInformation"></InputCheckbox>
                <label for="SaveLoginEdit" class="col-form-label">Save login information</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    public class LoginObject
    {
        public string Username = "";
        public string Password = "";
        public bool SaveLoginInformation = false;
    }

    private LoginObject loginData = new LoginObject();
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void LoginContributor()
    {
        IncrementCount();
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

If I click the "Click Me" button I don't get any errors on the Console, but if I click the "Login" button, I get the following console error:

```
counter:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: LoginContributor is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (counter:1)
```

The code still executes fine, but I don't like the console error and would like to know why it's showing up and how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because you using `onclick` instead `@onclick` on button. `onclick` expect javascript code, `@onclick` expect c# function.
Right:
`<button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="LoginContributor">Log In</button>`

Comment: Brien is using `OnValidSubmit=`

Comment: @HenkHolterman this has nothing to do with the error. Error occurr while login button click.

Comment: You are right about the cause, but you're still a little off on the solution.

Comment: @loject You are correct, Adding the @ to the onclick for the Login button removes the error.  It calls the method twice (I'm assuming since it's set on the OnValidSubmit and the button onclick).

EDIT: Fixed the double issue by removing the onclick and setting type to "submit"

Comment: @BrienKing - yes you are setting it twice so it's called twice.

Comment: Correct button is: `<button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">` , no click at all.

Comment: An explanation.  Any buttons declared as `type="submit"` (the default) are tied into the `EditForm` control. So when you click on the button, you kick off the validation process in `EditForm` which then calls `OnValidSubmit` if the `Model` passes validation.  You also have `OnSubmit`, which you use if you aren't doing validation, or wish to bypass validation.